# Subscription status showing as 'inactive' despite being set up for automatic payments

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm encountering an issue with my webhook route where the subscription status is being marked as 'inactive' despite it being set up for automatic payments. Below is the relevant code from my webhook route:
[stripe listening and stripe trigger is working:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxhWy.png)

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { headers } from 'next/headers'
import Stripe from 'stripe'
import { stripe } from '@/lib/stripe'
import { subscriptionCreated } from '@/lib/stripe/stripe-actions'

const stripeWebhookEvents = new Set([
  'product.created',
  'product.updated',
  'price.created',
  'price.updated',
  'checkout.session.completed',
  'customer.subscription.created',[enter image description here]
  'customer.subscription.updated',
  'customer.subscription.deleted',
])

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  let stripeEvent: Stripe.Event
  const body = await req.text()
  const sig = headers().get('Stripe-Signature')
  const webhookSecret =
    process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET_LIVE ?? process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
  try {
    if (!sig || !webhookSecret) {
      console.log(
        ' Error Stripe webhook secret or the signature does not exist.'
      )
      return
    }
    stripeEvent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig, webhookSecret)
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(` Error: ${error.message}`)
    return new NextResponse(`Webhook Error: ${error.message}`, { status: 400 })
  }

  try {
    if (stripeWebhookEvents.has(stripeEvent.type)) {
      const subscription = stripeEvent.data.object as Stripe.Subscription
      if (
        !subscription.metadata.connectAccountPayments &&
        !subscription.metadata.connectAccountSubscriptions
      ) {
        switch (stripeEvent.type) {
          case 'customer.subscription.created':
          case 'customer.subscription.updated': {
            if (subscription.status === 'active') {
              await subscriptionCreated(
                subscription,
                subscription.customer as string
              )
              console.log('CREATED FROM WEBHOOK ', subscription)
            } else {
              console.log(
                'SKIPPED AT CREATED FROM WEBHOOK  because subscription status is not active',
                subscription
              )
              break
            }
          }
          default:
            console.log(' Unhandled relevant event!', stripeEvent.type)
        }
      } else {
        console.log(
          'SKIPPED FROM WEBHOOK  because subscription was from a connected account not for the application',
          subscription
        )
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return new NextResponse(' Webhook Error', { status: 400 })
  }
  return NextResponse.json(
    {
      webhookActionReceived: true,
    },
    {
      status: 200,
    }
  )
}
```

I've attempted to troubleshoot the issue by inspecting the webhook route code provided above. Specifically, I checked the logic related to subscription status verification and the handling of webhook events. Additionally, I reviewed the Stripe documentation to ensure correct usage of the Stripe API methods. My expectation was that the subscription status would be correctly identified as 'active' and the relevant webhook events would trigger the expected actions, such as calling the subscriptionCreated function. However, despite these efforts, the subscription status continues to be marked as 'inactive' in the webhook response. I'm seeking assistance in identifying any potential errors in the code logic or configuration that may be causing this discrepancy.

However, when I run the code, I receive the following error:

```
SKIPPED AT CREATED FROM WEBHOOK  because subscription status is not active {
  id: 'sub_1OrloPSG8ioXseIHdi5dn65z',
  object: 'subscription',
  application: null,
  application_fee_percent: null,
  automatic_tax: { enabled: false, liability: null },
  billing_cycle_anchor: 1709836621,
  billing_cycle_anchor_config: null,
  billing_thresholds: null,
  cancel_at: null,
  cancel_at_period_end: false,
  canceled_at: null,
  cancellation_details: { comment: null, feedback: null, reason: null },
  collection_method: 'charge_automatically',
  created: 1709836621,
  currency: 'usd',
  current_period_end: 1712515021,
  current_period_start: 1709836621,
  customer: 'cus_PgwkOaDuHI9s9p',
  days_until_due: null,
  default_payment_method: null,
  default_source: null,
  default_tax_rates: [],
  description: null,
  discount: null,
  ended_at: null,
  invoice_settings: { account_tax_ids: null, issuer: { type: 'self' } },
  items: {
    object: 'list',
    data: [ [Object] ],
    has_more: false,
    total_count: 1,
    url: '/v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_1OrloPSG8ioXseIHdi5dn65z'
  },
  latest_invoice: 'in_1OrloPSG8ioXseIHwFmxn01w',
  livemode: false,
  metadata: {},
  next_pending_invoice_item_invoice: null,
  on_behalf_of: null,
  pause_collection: null,
  payment_settings: {
    payment_method_options: null,
    payment_method_types: null,
    save_default_payment_method: 'on_subscription'
  },
  pending_invoice_item_interval: null,
  pending_setup_intent: null,
  pending_update: null,
  plan: {
    id: 'price_1OrXvVSG8ioXseIHednf5dgO',
    object: 'plan',
    active: true,
    aggregate_usage: null,
    amount: 4900,
    amount_decimal: '4900',
    billing_scheme: 'per_unit',
    created: 1709783245,
    currency: 'usd',
    interval: 'month',
    interval_count: 1,
    livemode: false,
    metadata: {},
    nickname: 'Basic',
    product: 'prod_PgvnfWSWquxXA5',
    tiers_mode: null,
    transform_usage: null,
    trial_period_days: null,
    usage_type: 'licensed'
  },
  quantity: 1,
  schedule: null,
  start_date: 1709836621,
  status: 'incomplete',
  test_clock: null,
  transfer_data: null,
  trial_end: null,
  trial_settings: { end_behavior: { missing_payment_method: 'create_invoice' } },
  trial_start: null
}
```

Comment: The status of the above log looks to be 'incomplete' which happens when a payment fails, https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/overview. This is expected and you would need to use their one of their successful charge test cards, https://docs.stripe.com/testing#cards-responses to see that status change to 'active'. Can you try?